# Use of StorageLevel to improve performances

Tags: apache-spark, caching

I am trying to use the method `persist` applied to my dataframe to improve performances.

But I am totally lost in the multiple combinaison available. 
I executed this :

```
a = [True, False]
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        for k in a:
            for l in a:
                for m in [1,2]:
                    print(StorageLevel(i,j,k,l,m))
Disk Memory OffHeap Deserialized 1x Replicated
Disk Memory OffHeap Deserialized 2x Replicated
Disk Memory OffHeap Serialized 1x Replicated
Disk Memory OffHeap Serialized 2x Replicated
Disk Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated
Disk Memory Deserialized 2x Replicated
Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated
Disk Memory Serialized 2x Replicated
Disk OffHeap Deserialized 1x Replicated
Disk OffHeap Deserialized 2x Replicated
Disk OffHeap Serialized 1x Replicated
Disk OffHeap Serialized 2x Replicated
Disk Deserialized 1x Replicated
Disk Deserialized 2x Replicated
Disk Serialized 1x Replicated
Disk Serialized 2x Replicated
Memory OffHeap Deserialized 1x Replicated
Memory OffHeap Deserialized 2x Replicated
Memory OffHeap Serialized 1x Replicated
Memory OffHeap Serialized 2x Replicated
Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated
Memory Deserialized 2x Replicated
Memory Serialized 1x Replicated
Memory Serialized 2x Replicated
OffHeap Deserialized 1x Replicated
OffHeap Deserialized 2x Replicated
OffHeap Serialized 1x Replicated
OffHeap Serialized 2x Replicated
Deserialized 1x Replicated
Deserialized 2x Replicated
Serialized 1x Replicated
Serialized 2x Replicated
```

What does each option means ? Which one should I use, when, in which case ?

Comment: If there were a secret recipe, they wouldn't put to many possible combinations. You should use according to the resources and the type of job you need Spark to do, it's not just an ice cream flavor. Unfortunately this makes your question off-topic and I'm voting to close it.

Comment: @eliasah If i need to use them accordingly to my ressources, can you explain how each option is impacting which part of my ressources ?

Comment: @eliasah I would suggest to change question to "what it means, that" and here: Memory/Disk, Off Heap or On Heap, Serialized or Not